# How can I listen for keypress event on the whole page?

Tags: typescript, angular, keypress, key-bindings

I'm looking for a way to bind a function to my whole page (when a user presses a key, I want it to trigger a function in my component.ts)

It was easy in AngularJS with a `ng-keypress` but it does not work with `(keypress)="handleInput($event)"`.

I tried it with a div wrapper on the whole page but it doesn't seem to work.
it only works when the focus is on it.

```xml
<div (keypress)="handleInput($event)" tabindex="1">
```

Comment: Have you tried `window:keypress`?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

I would use [**@HostListener**](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) decorator within your component:

```typescript
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {

  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    this.key = event.key;
  }
}
```

There are also other options like:

**host property** within `@Component` decorator

Angular recommends using `@HostListener` decorator over host property https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03

```typescript
@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    '(document:keypress)': 'handleKeyboardEvent($event)'
  }
})
export class AppComponent {
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

**renderer.listen**

```typescript
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  globalListenFunc: Function;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalListenFunc = this.renderer.listen('document', 'keypress', e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // remove listener
    this.globalListenFunc();
  }
}
```

**Observable.fromEvent**

```typescript
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keypress').subscribe(e => {
      console.log(e);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Werking fine. import {HostListener } from '@angular/core' have to add. and call even anywhere in component. Even out side contructor also working fine

Comment: Thanks for this, but just a heads up for future readers: if you need the arrow keys, use keydown instead of keypress.

Comment: If you need the `esc` key, use `keyup` event. Thank to @TroelsLarsen

Comment: @yurzui ,how can I use this event for particular component.not on whole page

Comment: @yurzui How can I detect a `function-key` (F1, F2, F3, ...)?

Comment: @yurzui i wanted to ask one thing on this, this actually will trigger for the whole document what if i have multiple small components in the view and one is in focus i only want to trigger or listen to the click or mouse events for that component and all other components too have this but are not in focus ?

Comment: @arpit-meena Use keydown (or keyup) instead of keypress to catch function keys.

`@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])`

Comment: this won't detect 'escape'

Comment: Can someone explain why doing this in a directive does not work? Such as in the directive having the selector choose the `app-root` element. This does not seem to fire any keypress events.

Comment: @yurzui You can detect Function Keys by using the `keydown`/`keyup` events and then be sure to call `event.preventDefault()` on the event to prevent it being handled by your browser. (For instance if you don't stop it from bubbling up, your browser will open a help screen when you press `F1`.)

Comment: interestingly the new (angular 17) site mentions the opposite guide: Always prefer using the host property over HostBinding and HostListener.
https://angular.dev/guide/components/host-elements#:~:text=always%20prefer%20using%20the%20host%20property%20over%20%40hostbinding%20and%20%40hostlistener.%20

Answer (score 27):

Just to add to this in 2019 w Angular 8,

instead of keypress I had to use keydown

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
```

to

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
```

Working [Stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqnsu8)

Comment: Angular 9 report: both keypress and keydown would register normal "asdf" keys, but only keydown would get F4 and other function keys. Keypress could get some key combos like CTRL-Z, keydown interprets those separately (a CTRL key, then milliseconds later, a Z key).

Answer (score 22):

yurzui's answer didn't work for me, it might be a different RC version, or it might be a mistake on my part. Either way, here's how I did it with my component in Angular2 RC4 (which is now quite outdated).

```
@Component({
    ...
    host: {
        '(document:keydown)': 'handleKeyboardEvents($event)'
    }
})
export class MyComponent {
    ...
    handleKeyboardEvents(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        this.key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the same, just alternative syntax and you used `keydown` instead of `keypress`

Comment: Like I said, probably a mistake on my part, but that's what it took to get it to work for me. :)

Comment: What would be the benefit of this vs using document.addEventListener? Is it just an issue of abstracting away the DOM?

Comment: @Ixonal #2 on this articles describes better than I can: http://angularjs.blogspot.ca/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html Basically, it's not the 'Angular' way, because it's coupled with the browser, and it's not testable. Maybe not a big deal right now, but it's a good model to follow.

Comment: The latest docs recommend using @HostListener: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#-a-id-06-03-a-use-hostlistener-and-hostbinding-class-decorators

Comment: doesnt work!property 'key' does not exists in the current context.

Comment: You can't just copy-paste code and expect it to work without modifications @ritesh. You need to either define `key` as a class variable, or change the assignment to assign to a local variable.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to perform any event on any specific keyboard button press, in that case, you can use @HostListener. For this, you have to import HostListener in your component ts file.

**import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';** 
then use below function anywhere in your component ts file.

```
@HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  handleDeleteKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.key === 'Delete')
    {
      // remove something...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware `document:keypress` is deprecated. We should use `document:keydown` instead.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 2):

I think this does the best job

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/EventManager

for instance in app.component

```
constructor(private eventManager: EventManager) {
    const removeGlobalEventListener = this.eventManager.addGlobalEventListener(
      'document',
      'keypress',
      (ev) => {
        console.log('ev', ev);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: `addGlobalEventListener` is @deprecated — No longer being used in Ivy code. To be removed in version 14.

Answer (score 2):

I struggeled a little bit on this one so;
tshoemake provided the correct answer that also works for F keys.
To prevent the F key from executing it's original browser action, like search, also call the preventDefault() method.

add the following includes

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
```

and

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleTheKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "F2":
        this.myF2Action();
        event.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
}
```