# angular 2 ionic 2 handling events on keypress

Tags: angular, keyboard, ionic2

I have a bunch of ionic 2 cards which I want to flip on the press of a key (any key, it doesn't matter). The code looks like

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card (click)="setTime(7)" *ngIf="status == 'morning'" (keypress)="eventHandler($event)" style="width:80%">
        <img src="https://greatist.com/sites/default/files/Sleeping-Positions-feature.jpg"/>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

the .ts code

```
eventHandler(keyCode){
        alert('hey vikj');
  }
```

On pressing any key, my event handler is not fired.

Comment: It's set up correct, but the focus needs to be on the ion-card before it starts to listen. Click on the card and then press a key and it should work. If you want the focus to be on the entire page check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/angular-2-listen-for-keypress-event-on-whole-page

Comment: keypress won't fire for all keys(example backspace) try with keyup or keydown

Comment: @Z.Bagley if u post it as answer i can accept it as correct answer

Comment: Done, appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's set up correct, but the focus needs to be on the ion-card before it starts to listen. Click on the card and then press a key and it should work. If you want the focus to be on the entire page check out this question: 
[Angular 2 | listen for keypress event on whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/angular-2-listen-for-keypress-event-on-whole-page)

Answer (score 4):

you can use this function in input field

```
(keypress)="onChange($event.keyCode)"
```