# Angular2 Catch the Delete button press from keyboard event

Tags: angular, events

I have multiple records in the gridview. I have option to select multiple records from the gridview.

After selecting I want these selected records to be deleted.

Anybody know how can I call the delete event to be called in angular2 when **delete button is pressed from keyboard ?**

Comment: The docs show how to handle the Enter key. You can follow the same process for the delete key: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter

Comment: just simply check the `Delete` key code and perform actions accordingly

Answer (score 8):

If you want to perform any event on any specific keyboard button press, in that case, you can use @HostListener. For this, you have to import HostListener in your component ts file. I can use the following function to perform ***delete keyboard press.***

**import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';** 
then use below function anywhere in your component ts file.

```
    @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
      handleDeleteKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if(event.key === 'Delete')
        {
          // remove something... or call remove funtion this.remove();
        }
      }
remove(){ 
// code..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This way I used in my project to handle delete button use

`@HostListener('document:keydown.delete', ['$event'])`

I share for whom concern

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.delete', ['$event'])
onDeleteComponent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.removeItem(this.selectedDashboardItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In angular2 using @HostListener to bind the keyboard events worked for me.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {

  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    this.key = event.key;
  }
}
```

For more details, you can check the details here.

[How can I listen for keypress event on the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page)

Comment: This works only for letters/number keys, but not for DEL