# Angular 5, how to detect user inactivity

Tags: angular

Aside from using IdleJS and ngDoCheck(), how can we detect user inactivity in Angular 5?


Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925361/how-to-give-session-idle-timeout-in-angular-6/61773199#61773199

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could try with this :

```js
export class AppComponent {

  userActivity;
  userInactive: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.setTimeout();
    this.userInactive.subscribe(() => console.log('user has been inactive for 3s'));
  }

  setTimeout() {
    this.userActivity = setTimeout(() => this.userInactive.next(undefined), 3000);
  }

  @HostListener('window:mousemove') refreshUserState() {
    clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
    this.setTimeout();
  }
}
```

Seems to work in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9wcuw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) : open the console, don't move your mouse for 3 seconds : you see the message.

Refresh the page, move your mouse on the preview (right side) for a couple of seconds : the message doesn't pop until you stop for 3s.

You can obviously export that into a service, because as you can see, I'm using only a class to do that.

Comment: Well you can try with the blitz ... But sure, keep me updated

Comment: it works. I have just tried. awesome answer and work you have there! thank you so much!

Comment: I want to use a timer that runs a decreased time like activity check for 10 mins after 9 min timer should run decreasing the time but without any NPM

Comment: Remember that this assumes the user is using a mouse. That might not work great for mobile users, or for those using screen readers or just keyboards.

Comment: If using small idle time values (such as a few seconds), the code above may be run outside of Angular Zone, so that it doesn't trigger changeDetection too often.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 12):

Service that solves this problem (instead of a component as the accepted answer), handles touch, type and mouse. Emits an event N seconds after the user has been idle, and when he 'wakes up'. Works on Angular 11:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { fromEvent, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class IdleService {

  public idle$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  public wake$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  isIdle = false;
  private idleAfterSeconds = 10;
  private countDown;

  constructor() {
    // Setup events
    fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').subscribe(() => this.onInteraction());
    fromEvent(document, 'touchstart').subscribe(() => this.onInteraction());
    fromEvent(document, 'keydown').subscribe(() => this.onInteraction());
  }

  onInteraction() {
    // Is idle and interacting, emit Wake
    if (this.isIdle) {
      this.isIdle = false;
      this.wake$.next(true);
    }

    // User interaction, reset start-idle-timer
    clearTimeout(this.countDown);
    this.countDown = setTimeout(() => {
      // Countdown done without interaction - emit Idle
      this.isIdle = true;
      this.idle$.next(true);
    }, this.idleAfterSeconds * 1_000)
  }
}
```

Usage, inject in constructor and use:

```js
constructor(private idleService: IdleService) {  
  idleService.idle$.subscribe(s => console.log('im idle, zzz'));
  idleService.wake$.subscribe(s => console.log('im awake!'));
}
```

Comment: Might be adequate to change `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject` with an initial value that represents an 'awake' state upon app start, to prevent a false 'idle' state in the subscribers of `idle$` and `wake$` when the app just starts.

Comment: Nice addition to your solution would be to make the service get the idle duration through the constructor (passed in) rather then have it hard coded.
Otherwise great work

Comment: Nice suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked fine for me. the problem I faced with the accepted answer is, it only focuses on mouse events and no keyboard keypress events

```
    userActivity;
    userInactive: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    constructor( ) {
        
        this.setTimeout();
        this.userInactive.subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/lock']);
        });
       
        }
```

- These events check if user is idle for a specific time and then subscribe to a different ( lock ) screen

  ```
   keyPress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
       clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
       this.setTimeout();
   }
   setTimeout(): void {
       this.userActivity = setTimeout(() => this.userInactive.next(undefined), 900000);
   }

   @HostListener('window:mousemove') refreshUserState() {
       clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
       this.setTimeout();
   }
  ```

Comment: I like that you take into account the keyboard activity and not just mouseevents.  FYI I had to add "@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])" to the keyPress event.  I also used keydown instead of keypress based on the information in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page/37363257

Comment: I am also adding touchEvent for mobile device uses: @HostListener('touch', ['$event'])
    touchEvent() ...

Comment: @ThomasJahncke thanks a lot. it really gave me an insight :)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to use this package [angular-user-idle](https://github.com/rednez/angular-user-idle)

I have not used it in real application but might be slightly more robust than the solution proposed in the previous answer.

Comment: This seems to work nicely and has more options than the accepted answer

Comment: A better option for this is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core?activeTab=readme. I tried both, this one is easier to implement, has more activity on the package and it has a function that tells you when idle stops. This was perfect for me. It took an hour to implement, configure and test in my Angular 16 application.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with based on previous answers:

```js
// Will store the limit amount of time a user can be idle
inactivityTimeLimit: number = 60;

// Will monitor user's activity
userActivity: any;

// Will monitor the alert time (80% of the idle time limit)
userActivityAlert: any;

// Stores the alert watch (interval)
userAlertInterval: any;

// Alert is visible or not (HTML)
isActivityAlertOpen: boolean = false;

// Displays (in the alert) how many seconds remain until the user gets logged out
alertTimeLeft: number;

// Will monitor user's idleness
userInactive: Subject<any>;

// In Angular, will emmit when the user us supposed to be logged out/off.
@Output() logoutTrigger = new EventEmitter();

constructor() {  
  this.userInactive = new Subject();

  // Will listen for when user finally idles for the limit amount of time
  this.userInactive.subscribe({
    next: () => {
      // Closes the alert box/modal/notification
      this.isActivityAlertOpen = false;
      // Emmits to trigger logout/logoff
      this.logoutTrigger.emit();
    },
  });

  // Starts the "watch" that monitors activity
  this.refreshUserState();
}

// Starts/Restarts the activity monitor counter
// Will be triggered every time the user performs mouse clicks or moves, keypressess or touches screen (mobile)
refreshUserState() {
  // Clears out any previous Timeouts
  clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
  
  // Creates a new Timeout
  // Will call next() on userInactive once it reaches the max amount of idleness time
  this.userActivity = setTimeout(() => this.userInactive.next(undefined), this.inactivityTimeLimit * 1000);

  // Makes sure the alert box is closed
  this.isActivityAlertOpen = false;

  // The alert's amount of time is 80% of the max amount of idleness time
  // Meaning, once there's 20% of time left to finish, an alert will be displayed
  
  // timeToAlert === 80% of the total amount of idleness time
  const timeToAlert = (this.inactivityTimeLimit / 10) * 8;
  // alerTimeLeft === amount of time the alert shall be visible (20%)
  this.alertTimeLeft = (this.inactivityTimeLimit / 10) * 2;

  clearTimeout(this.userActivityAlert);
  clearInterval(this.userAlertInterval);

  // Starts the clock
  this.userActivityAlert = setTimeout(() => {
    // Once 80% of the idleness time goes, opens the alert
    this.isActivityAlertOpen = true;
    // Once the alert opens, removes 1 from the alertTimeLeft every second, updating the message being displayed ("...there's 6/5/4 seconds remaining...")
    this.userAlertInterval = setInterval(() => this.alertTimeLeft -= 1, 1000);
  }, timeToAlert * 1000);
}

// Listeners for activity monitoring
// Every time one of these events are triggered, all the "watches" are reseted
@HostListener('window:mousemove') mouseMove() {
  if (this.hasViewBeenInitiated) this.refreshUserState();
}

@HostListener('keydown') keyboardClick() {
  if (this.hasViewBeenInitiated) this.refreshUserState();
}

@HostListener('touchstart') screenTouched() {
  if (this.hasViewBeenInitiated) this.refreshUserState();
}

@HostListener('touchmove') screenDragged() {
  if (this.hasViewBeenInitiated) this.refreshUserState();
}
```

I set 60 seconds as a standard value just for testing, but I'd probably use 600 seconds (10 minutes) as a good amount of time for a user to be idle. I guess the appropriate amount of time would depende on what kind of project you're running.

It's actually quite simple, but it works as intended. Thanks to all the previous answers. Like I said, they helped out a lot.