# Listener event in Angular

Tags: angular

I am developing an application and looking for an event/method which gets called everytime irrespective of the user interaction or not with the application so that I can write my logic to render the timeout dialog.  Can someone suggest me how this could be achieved in the app.component.ts.

anonymous function(){

//listen to any state of the application, be it user clicks, mouse move, ideal, keyboards events 
  so that my function can be invoked.

PS:- idle package just works for ideal state with a timeout.

With the idle package you can just determine the idle state of the application but I am looking for something which can be executed irrespective of it.

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give session idle timeout in angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925361/how-to-give-session-idle-timeout-in-angular-6)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925361/how-to-give-session-idle-timeout-in-angular-6/54925477#54925477.

Comment: No , please read that I would like to execute my logic irrespective of whether user is ideal or not. I have already implemented the idle flow but it doesn't suffice my objective.

Comment: @DJ-, Provide working example in stackblitz with the code that you have used..

Comment: I am still trying to figure out a way that's what my question is how can i achieve it. Once I have it, i shall be able to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be like this,
consider you have a variable **appState**  in a service called **appService**. Create a directive and apply it on `<app-component activeDirective></app-component>`. This directive will listen for mouse movements, user click, keyboard click etc. If any of such things happen, change the **appState** to **active**.

In the same **appService** create a timer function. Let's say your idle time is 10s. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651463/how-do-i-call-a-function-in-every-10-seconds-in-angular-2). So every five second check the state of **appState** variable. If it's **active** make it **idle**. If it's **idle** perform your idle function flow.

Comment: ok, thanks for your response, how do i listen to a mouse movements, user clicks keyboard etck, Appreciate if you can tell me the package or example to look through.

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Have you used HostListener before? If not you can see that for identifying button clicks, mouse movements. See this asnwer for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page/37363257
If you are stuck anywhere tell me.

Comment: Thanks, I think this helps in capturing me all the clicks on the application to track down which is good. However, just wondering if I had to determine the session idle should i go with Idle package.