# Angular 7 how to navigate trough ngb-tabset tabs by key?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am using the tabset component of ng-bootstrap for my angular project and I am wondering if it's possible to navigate through the different tabs of my ngb-tabset by using the keyboard keys (i.e. "alt" key or "alt"+"n" keys)?

My code looks like:

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="Tab 1">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      Some Content
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Tab 2">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
Some Content
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Tab 3">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      Some Content
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: There's a method `select` in the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/api. Maybe you can code an keypress event handler that selects the next tab, with this method. Show us your attempt.

Comment: Here's a little help for handling keypress events : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page