# Generic parameters for HostListener

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a Directive that accepts a string to pass to HostListener. Basically a Directive to stop event propagation for any event.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[crmDisableEventPropagation]'
})
export class DisableClickPropagation {
  public myStr: string;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: any): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Right now I have `'click'` hardwired as the HostListener parameter. But I am wondering if there is a way (maybe using generics or something similar) to use this one Directive for any kind of event without having to create a different directive per event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use event name as a generic parameter in `@HostListener` decorator because it should be know at compile time.

But you can handle events with another approach.

For example, you can try [Renderer2.listen](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen)

```typescript
import { Directive, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[crmDisableEventPropagation]'
})
export class DisableClickPropagation implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('crmDisableEventPropagation') event: string;

  listener: () => void;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private host: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listener = this.renderer.listen(
      this.host.nativeElement,
      this.event,
      e => e.stopPropagation()
    );
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.listener();
  }
}
```

Now use it as follows:

**some.html**

```typescript
<div crmDisableEventPropagation="click">
```

Note that you can also use different approach like observable `fromEvent`

See also [How can I listen for keypress event on the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page)