# How to click a button (not inside form) with Enter key press in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular 8 and need to default click a button on a page when `Enter` key is pressed. The thing is the button is not inside any form. There are other buttons beside it. Clicking them works fine, but I need to press this one on `Enter` key press. I read some suggestions but none seems fitting in. I tried `(keyup.Enter)="search()" but it didn't work.

```
<button
            id="log-button"
            (click)="search()"
            color="primary"
            [disabled]="logForm.invalid"
            class="link-button"
            >Search</button
        >
```

P.S. - Though there is `logForm` here but it's only for validation purpose and there isn't any `<form>` tags in the html where this button is placed.

Any help us much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to key-down event inside the ts file

```
 @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
  if(this.key === "Enter")
    your event
  }
```

[excemple of lisener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page/37363257)

Comment: I just figured that out mate after reading number of solutions and none worked. I figured it and your reply popped. Thanks a bunch though. This one works like a charm. Accepting it.