# How to map f1 keyboard shortcut in angular page?

Tags: angular

I tried mapping with different key like `f2`, `ctrl+f` and it's working but when i am trying to map with `f1` key so by default chrome browser help page will be open.
So is there any way to change default `f1` key behavior on my angular webpage.

Using `Angular 9`, Binding key using `HotKeys` method.

Comment: you can refer here - https://netbasal.com/diy-keyboard-shortcuts-in-your-angular-application-4704734547a2

Comment: Thanks Krunal, but the requirement is to map with F1 key only. As i mentioned i already achieved keyboard shortcuts on my page with others keys.

Comment: refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362488/how-can-i-listen-for-keypress-event-on-the-whole-page/37363257)